# golang grouping in mysql query

Tags: mysql, go

I have a mysql query, struct and code like that:

```
sqlQuery := "SELECT group_concat(Id), Title from Tbl WHERE SomeField = 3 GROUP BY Title ORDER BY Title LIMIT 20;"
type SomeStruct struct {
    IDs            []int    `json:"ids"`
    Title          string   `json:"title"`
    SomeField      int      `json:"somefield"`
}

type SomeMap map[string]interface{}

var SomeObject []SomeMap

row, err := db.Query(sqlQuery)
checkErr(err)
for row.Next() {
   var ids []int
   var title string
   var somefield int

   err = row.Scan(&ids, &title, &somefield)
   someMap := SomeMap{"ids":ids, "title": title, "somefield": somefield}
   someObject = append(SomeObject, someMap)
}
```

How can I unmashal my object to struct where IDs look like []int type because golang tells that it might be []uint8 ??

Comment: There's something at play here that is not indicated by the information you've provided. Are those IDs in the database specifically unsigned bytes?

Comment: Which mysql driver are you using?

Comment: @mkopriva `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`

Comment: group_concat seems to return a string of concatenated values, so you'll have to first scan ids into a string, then in Go you can do strings.Split and strconv.Atoi or some such thing.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear in databese Id its int type column

Comment: @mkopriva thank you

Comment: @mkopriva that would explain the `[]uint8` aka `[]byte` aka `string`.